# How can I create a key combination that sends the content of a markdown code cell to a tmux pane with slime?

Tags: tmux, python, plugin-slime

I am a happy user of [nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R), which enables to send R markdown chunks to an R console with `<localleader>ca`. R cells code blocks look like this in R markdown files:

````
```{r}
head(faithful)
```
````

When I edit python code, I send code to the console with [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime). I use the slime key combination `ctrl-c` `ctrl-c` to send a line of code and `vip` followed by `ctrl-c` to send a code block. I also sometimes edit jupyter notebooks that were converted to markdown files using jupytext. In that case the python cells look like this:

````
```python
from plotnine.data import faithful
faithful.head()
—
````

My current strategy is to either select those lines or to introduce space above an below for easy selection with `vip`. But I think there can be a better way.

How can I create a key combination that sends the content of this code cell to a tmux pane with slime?

Related issue: https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/issues/295

Related plugin: https://github.com/hanschen/vim-ipython-cell

Comment: Not sure about slime, but for tmux see https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone and `:Twrite`

Comment: Is that a hyphen that ends the block in your second example?

Comment: @mattb, the code block seems to end with an "em dash". I pasted the output of [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).